# Accessing 3 dimension array in ionic 3

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic3

Here is my JSON file which contains all the data

```
{
"item1": [
    {
        "seller": "5b4724b9683087332440d3bd",
        "subject": "Price",
        "id": "5b61c14143ef6a1610695105",
        "user": "5b5772930e74ea36b445659b",
        "message": "High price"
    },
    {
        "seller": "5b4724b9683087332440d3bd",
        "subject": "Customer Service",
        "id": "5b61c2e143ef6a1610695106",
        "user": "5b5772930e74ea36b445659b",
        "message": "Good customer service"
    }
],
"item2": [
    {
        "product": "5b561de369716706c81b4d65",
        "id": "5b5c801b0b7302174c135c69",
        "user": "5b5772930e74ea36b445659b",
        "message": "Good product with a high quality display"
    }
]
```

From the provider, I'm getting data from the API by calling the get method as follow. It's working properly

```
 getCustomerFeedbackByID(cid) {
return new Promise(resolve => {
  this.http.get(this.postapiUrl + '/user/' + cid + '/feedbacks').subscribe(data => {
    resolve(data);
  }, err => {
    console.log(err);
  });
});
```

then I wrote a function to access the data inside the JSON file. For certain depth, it read the data. But I cannot get the seller name and other attributes

getCustomerFeedback() {

```
this.cust.getCustomerFeedbackByID(this.custID)

  .then(data => {
    this.custFeedback.push(data);
    console.log("feedbacks:" + this.custFeedback)

    this.custFeedback.forEach(element => {

      this.feedback.push(element.item1)

      console.log("element seller:" + element.seller);

    });
  })
```

}

As the output of **console.log("element seller:"+element.seller)** it give me as **Undefine**

Please, someone, help with this to get the values of this JSON file to display in the ionic 3 mobile app

Comment: You don't have a property `seller` on the `element` variable. That variable is essentially the result from your service since you pushed it onto the array that you are looping over. You can see this as the `item1` property is on that variable. Are you wanting to loop over your `item1` property to get to each of the items in that, which does have a `seller` property?

Comment: Yes I want to loop over item1 property . Seller property contain a string value which is the id of seller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to access the path to the feedback array such as

```
 this.custFeedback.forEach(element => {

         this.feedback.push(element.item1)
     });
```

then feedback array has the item1 element. So you can access that array to get the seller details as

```
    this.feedback.forEach(data =>{

         console.log("element seller:" + data['seller']);

     });
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to access *seller* element which is inside **item1**, but your code is trying to access it from the parent level, where only *item1* and *item2*  is present. I guess the code below will help you.

```
this.cust.getCustomerFeedbackByID(this.custID)
    .then(data => {
         this.custFeedback.push(data);
         console.log("feedbacks:" + this.custFeedback)
         this.custFeedback.forEach(element => {

             this.feedback.push(element.item1)
         });
         this.feedback.forEach(data =>{
             if (data['seller'] {
             console.log("element seller:" + data['seller']);
             }
         });

     });
```